# Equivalence between OLS estimators in matrix and summation form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression, estimation

I am struggling to reconcile the OLS estimators that I commonly see expressed in matrix and summation form. In matrix form, it takes the following form:

$\hat β$ = $(X'X)^{-1}X'y$

In summation form, it typically looks like the following:

$ \hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum(X_i – \bar{X}) (Y_i – \bar{Y})} {\sum(X_i – \bar{X})^2}$

I am struggling to reconcile these; in my mind, the bottom should be more like this:

$ \hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum(X_iY_i)} {\sum(X_i)^2}$

I am not sure where the means emerge in the matrix notation.

Comment: Should be $\hat \beta=(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$; missing transpose

Comment: Fixed, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $X_i$ is scalar, and $X=(X_1,...,X_n)'$,

$$\hat \beta=(X'X)^{-1}X'Y=\frac{\sum_i X_iY_i}{\sum_i X_i^2}$$

is the OLS estimator for $\beta$ in the equation without the intercept, $Y_i=X_i\beta+\epsilon_i,$ while

$$\hat \beta=\frac{\sum_i (X_i-\bar X)(Y_i-\bar Y)}{\sum_i (X_i-\bar X)^2}$$
is the OLS estimator for $\beta$ in the equation with the intercept, $Y_i=\alpha+X_i\beta+\epsilon_i.$

---

Update: Note that $(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$ is more general than appears at first sight; indeed, it subsumes the second formula if we allow the regressor to be a column vector that includes a "$1$" for an intercept term.  To see this, let $\tilde X_i=(1,X_i)'$ for $X_i$ scalar. Let $X=(\tilde X_1,...,\tilde X_n)'$, which is a $n\times 2$ matrix. Then we have

$$(X'X)^{-1}X'Y=(\sum_i \tilde X_i\tilde X_i')^{-1}\sum_i \tilde X_iY_i\\
=\left[\sum_{i}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & X_{i}\\
X_{i} & X_{i}^{2}
\end{array}\right)\right]^{-1}\sum_{i}\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
X_{i}
\end{array}\right)Y_{i}\\
=\left[n\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \bar{X}\\
\bar{X} & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}X_{i}^{2}
\end{array}\right)\right]^{-1}n\left(\begin{array}{c}
\bar{Y}\\
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}X_{i}Y_{i}
\end{array}\right)\\
=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}X_{i}^{2}-\bar{X}^{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}X_{i}^{2} & -\bar{X}\\
-\bar{X} & 1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
\bar{Y}\\
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}X_{i}Y_{i}
\end{array}\right).
$$
The second component is then the estimate of the slope:
$$\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}X_{i}Y_{i}-\bar{X}\bar{Y}}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}X_{i}^{2}-\bar{X}^{2}}=\frac{\sum_{i}(X_{i}-\bar{X})(Y_{i}-\bar{Y})}{\sum_{i}(X_{i}-\bar{X})^{2}}.$$

Comment: I see, so they are entirely different values to begin with. That make sense, though I am still unsure how the mean emerges in the second equation and what the analogue to that in the first equation would be. If we actually did the matrix multiplication, would we not just get a K x 1 matrix for the K regressors? How does the one-variable case (second formula) involve the means of y and x?

Comment: @JKim59817, I have updated my answer-lemme know if that makes sense.